# Computing Jaccard Similarity in Java

Tags: java

I have following the code that loop through array list(mainItems) and find the most similar two arrays and put them in sortedTransactions. It is working fine for small data (10000 transactions) but it is running forever for 88000 transactions. What can be done to make it work for big data.

```
import java.util.*;

    public class Sort {

    static private  List<Transactions> trans = ReadFile.transactions;
    static public   List<int[]> mainItems;
    static public   ArrayList<int[]> sortedTransactions = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    static {
        mainItems = new ArrayList<int[]>();

        for (Transactions t : trans) {
            mainItems.add(t.getItems());
        }
    }

    static private  double jaccardSimilarity(int[] a, int[] b) {

        Set<Integer> s1 = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
        for(int i =0; i< a.length; i++){
            s1.add(a[i]);
        }
        Set<Integer> s2 = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
        for(int i =0; i< b.length; i++){
            s2.add(b[i]);
        }

        Set<Integer> intersection = new LinkedHashSet<>(s1);
        intersection.retainAll(s2);

        Set<Integer> union = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(s1); 
        union.addAll(s2); 

        double jaccardSimilarity = (double)intersection.size()/ (double)union.size();
        //System.out.println(intersection);
        return jaccardSimilarity;
    }

    static private boolean isAllEqual(List<Double> a){

        for(int i=1; i<a.size(); i++){
            if(a.get(0) != a.get(i)){
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }


    static public void generatePairs() {

        for (int i = 0; i < mainItems.size() - 1; i++) {

            if (!sortedTransactions.contains(mainItems.get(i))) {

                List<Double> myd = new ArrayList<Double>();
                List<int[]> mys = new ArrayList<int[]>();

                for (int j = i + 1; j < mainItems.size(); j++) {

                    if (!sortedTransactions.contains(mainItems.get(j))) {

                        myd.add(jaccardSimilarity(mainItems.get(i),mainItems.get(j)));
                        mys.add(mainItems.get(j));
                    }
                }

                if (isAllEqual(myd) == false) {

                    sortedTransactions.add(mainItems.get(i));
                    sortedTransactions.add(mys.get(maxValue(myd)));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static private int maxValue(List<Double> d) {

        double max = d.get(0);
        int f = 0;

        for(int i =1; i< d.size(); i++){

            if(d.get(i) > max){

                max= d.get(i); 
                f= i; 
            }
        }
        return f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Without running this locally it's difficult to confirm, but rather than brute force iterating through the list in `maxValue`, you could try a `Collections` sort on it to put the list in numerical order largest to smallest, then pick the first value. Sorting in Java is pretty quick and well optimised. Unfortunately, improving the performance of a program with many loops often requires a total rethink of the structure. The following library includes a Jaccard similarity implementation and may be of use - https://github.com/tdebatty/java-string-similarity

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to create the union set (union(s1, s2).size() is s1.size() + s2.size() - intersection(s1, s2).size()).

```
static private double jaccardSimilarity(int[] a, int[] b) {

    Set<Integer> s1 = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        s1.add(a[i]);
    }
    Set<Integer> s2 = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        s2.add(b[i]);
    }

    final int sa = s1.size();
    final int sb = s2.size();
    s1.retainAll(s2);
    final int intersection = s1.size();
    return 1d / (sa + sb - intersection) * intersection;
}
```